# Java type casting problems when overrideing equals()

Tags: java, casting, overriding, equals

I'm trying to override the equals() method for my class Vertex. Each vertex has a field `String source`.

If the parameter other_vertex is not a Vertex instance, I want equals() to return false.
If the parameter other_vertex is a Vertex instance, I want to test if the source strings are equal (by the default String equals(), and if true return true, if false return false.

My faulty code is

```
@Override
    public boolean equals(Object other_vertex) {
        if (!(other_vertex instanceof Vertex)) { 
            return false; 
        } 
        else {
            return (this.getSourceString()).equals(other_vertex.getSourceString());
        }
    }
```

This is giving me the compiler error "The method getSourceString() is undefined for the type Object" for the 7th line.
`getSourceString()` is properly defined for a Vertex.

How do I write the code to get the compiler to recognize that this is only executed if `other_vertex` is a Vertex?

Comment: You have to cast it, like `((Vertex)other_vertex).getSourceString()`.

Comment: The expression `(other_vertex instanceof Vertex)` does not implicitly cast `other_vertex`, it only checks the type. One would have to explicitly cast it within the `else`-block: `Vertex asVertex = (Vertex) other_vertex;`. Alternatively, with Java 14+, one can use pattern matching: `} else (other_vertex instanceof Vertext asVertex) { ... }`. As an aside: in Java, variable names should be written in `camelCase`, not `snake_case`.

Answer (score 1):

Notice

```
public boolean equals(Object other_vertex) {
                      ^^^^^^
```

You must cast `other_vertex` to `Vertex` in order to access the method.

```
return (this.getSourceString()).equals(((Vertex)other_vertex).getSourceString());
```

This is safe because you've already established that the down-cast is valid.